# Retrieve files from Amazon AWS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The company I work for had a developer load a site on Amazon AWS and I need to retrieve those html files or find out what they used. We are making some changes and I can't find the html files they used. I have been reading up on how the AWS works and it's so confusing.

I went into the S3 because that's where I thought they would be and there are two buckets but all they have are images that are used on the site. If someone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually easiest to start at the source.

Where does your domain name point?

If you happen to be running Linux or Mac OSX, you can run `dig www.example.com` to find the DNS records for your domain.

If you see some `CNAME` records pointing to something like `www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` then that's where the website is pointing.

If your website has dynamic content, implemented using a server-side language like PHP or Python then you may be running a server on EC2, Amazon's Elastic Compute Cloud. If that's the case you will need to log on to the machine in order to get your files. You should be able to use http://console.aws.amazon.com to look for any running EC2 instances.

It's also possible that the server is running elsewhere on the Internet, and only the image files are being hosted with Amazon.

If you can tell me your domain name I can find out more for you by looking at public DNS records.

Comment: I ran the dig and found this: elb021383-1184683836.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   So I have been looking in EC2 and everything and still can't find it?

Comment: So ELB is amazon's Elastic Load Balancer - that means your site IS hosted, at least in part, on Amazon EC2.  For info on Elastic Load Balancer, check out http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: Also, that ELB url has 'us-east-1' so make sure you select "US East (N. Virginia)" in the top right of the http://console.aws.amazon.com site - then select "EC2" from the "Services" button on the top left. You should then see a "Load Balancers" option in the menu along the left side. There should be something in there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the location and on the EC2 Dashboard I saw Load Balancers but there is nothing in there and says Creat Load Balancer...

Comment: Hmm, I went to that elb url and it took me to Heroku - so, your website is hosted at Heroku.com - so you'll have to log in there to get access.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do that URL as well. I will have to get that information from them. I appreciate your help in all of this. Sounds like I need to learn AWS more because they have great capabilities!